# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name empty in one HttpHandler but has a value in another

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httphandler

I have two `HttpHandlers`. One intercepts for any pdf file request in the url, the other for an xml request. In pdf file handler I get the username from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` but when a request is made for xml file `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is always null.

The `web.config` section to intercept the handlers looks like this:

```
<add verb="*" path="/calderdale/*.pdf" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CalderDaleAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />
<add verb="GET" path="/Pallative/*.xml" type="NES.HiLo.Security.PallativeAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />
```

Authentication section

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="KFCSAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" 
          slidingExpiration="true" path="/" domain=".scot.nhs.uk" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
<system.webServer>
   <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />-->
   <handlers>
      <add name="Pallative Handler" path="/Pallative/*.xml" verb="GET" 
           modules="IsapiModule" 
           scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" 
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
      <add name="Calderdale Handler" path="/calderdale/*.pdf" verb="GET" 
           modules="IsapiModule" 
           scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" 
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
       <!--<add name="Pallative Handler" path="Pallative/pallative_doc.html" 
                verb="GET" modules="IsapiModule" 
                scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
                resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" 
                preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: remove the first dot from `domain=".scot.nhs.uk"`, make it `domain="scot.nhs.uk"` and tell me if works.

Comment: Sorry that does not make any difference. I shall also mention that the value for the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is emtpy instead of null as I put in the title.